# Extraer objectos de JSON con Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Una consulta a una API me devuelve el siguiente JSON:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fields": {
        "Name": "Gadget",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Quantity": 503
       }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "fields": {
        "Name": "Widget",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Quantity": 2357
       }
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "fields": {
        "Name": "Gizmo",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Quantity": 92
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

Necesito devolver con javascript un nuevo JSON que contenga dentro todos los objectos "fields" para poder generar una tabla.

Creo que es posible realizarlo con la función **map** pero desconozco cómo llevarlo a cabo.

**Gracias**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar un `map()` e iterar sobre fields.

```js
const { value } = {
  value: [
    {
      id: "2",
      fields: {
        Name: "Gadget",
        Color: "Red",
        Quantity: 503
      }
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      fields: {
        Name: "Widget",
        Color: "Blue",
        Quantity: 2357
      }
    },
    {
      id: "7",
      fields: {
        Name: "Gizmo",
        Color: "Green",
        Quantity: 92
      }
    }
  ]
};
const other = value.map(data => data.fields)
console.log(other);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Funcionó como esperaba

Answer (score -1):

Podrías crear un nuevo objeto, en donde su clave será llamado `fields`, y su valor será lo que te devolverá el `map()`. El `map()` te devolverá los valores de todas las claves `fields` en un arreglo, y como los valores son objetos, el `map()` te devolverá un arreglo de objetos:

```
let result = {
  "fields": json.value.map(item => item.fields)
};
```

Ejemplo:

```js
let json = {
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fields": {
        "Name": "Gadget",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Quantity": 503
       }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "fields": {
        "Name": "Widget",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Quantity": 2357
       }
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "fields": {
        "Name": "Gizmo",
        "Color": "Green",
        "Quantity": 92
       }
    }
  ]
};

let result = {
  "fields": json.value.map(item => item.fields)
};

console.log(result);
```